# Может ли для  executable c -rdynamic понадобиться ключ gcc -fpic?

Tags: gcc, linux

Делаю в Linux (ubuntu)

```
gcc -c -fpic f1.c
gcc -shared -o testlib.so f1.o
gcc a.c -rdynamic -ldl
```

Полученный executable (в примере a.out) через dlopen() загружает testlib.so и вызывает функцию (скажем, f1()) в ней. Эта функция вызывает f2(), которая определена в a.out.

Как видно, a.out делаю без -fpic. *Все работает (вроде бы...).*

**Вопрос,** может ли (и при каких условиях) потребоваться компилировать с **-fpic** код,  который потом будет линковаться в executable с ключем **-rdynamic** ?

Упоминаний о такой связи -fpic с -rdynamic в сети я не нашел. Может быть у кого-то есть **личные наблюдения ?**

Comment: А кто его знает. Что dll'и строятся -fpic -- так это понятно, виндовых фокусов с перемещением dll только не хватало. А зачем исполняемому файлу, у которого адреса начинаются с нуля ещё и быть позиционно-независимым -- хз...

Ну а -rdynamic -- это капризы dlopen?

Comment: хз... - этто точно. Поэтому и спросил.

"Капризы dlopen" - не понял.

Флаг линкера **-rdynamic** говорит динамическому загрузчику, что внешние символы (функции, глобальные переменные)  executable надо поместить в глобальную таблицу имен (насколько я понимаю). Таким образом они становятся доступны динамически загружаемым модулям (библиотекам), ссылки на них автоматически разрешаются.

Вот из-за этих "обратных" ссылок (из .so на **имя** в executale) у меня и возникли сомнения.

Comment: Только, если я правильно прочитал, -rdynamic говорит линкеру (ld) поместить имена, даже не используемые в глобальную таблицу. А вот чем при разрешении ссылок из .so может помочь позиционная независимость исполняемого файла -- вообще непонятно.

И насчёт личных наблюдений -- вряд ли. Это же надо додуматься из .so ссылаться на имена, которые присутствуют в нескольких исполняемых бинарниках, и не передавать их каким-то образом, а отдать на обработку загрузчику. Мрак и ужас.

Comment: @alexlz, не очень понимаю, что Вас смущает. Нигде не читали ? Ну, неохота мне плодить библиотеки общие для бинарника и динамических модулей.

Comment: Во-первых, почему функции при этом желательно включать не в dll, а в исполняемый файл. Во-вторых, я писал про *несколько* исполняемых файлов.

Comment: @alexlz, про **несколько** исполняемых файлов это Вы придумали. 

У меня один исполняемый ("главный") динамически (по запросам) подключает несколько .so (dll-ки в винде). Функции из них, вызываемые (опять же внешними http json rpc запросами) могут обращаться к функциям некой среды, которая поддерживается "главным". По крайней мере на данном этапе развиития проекта такая архитектура.

Это вкратце.

--

По сути заданного вопроса (про -fpic для "главного") Вы что-то определенное сказать можете ?

Comment: Не очень понятно, почему для исполняемого файла используется `-fpic`, хотя для исполняемых есть специальный флаг `-fPIE`. Ссылка по этой теме http://www.openbsd.org/papers/nycbsdcon08-pie/

Comment: @user1056837, не то, чтобы `-fPIC` использовался (и без него вроде работает). Вопрос-то про то, *может ли* (и если да, то в какой ситуации) *потребоваться*, чтобы код функции в executable, которая ищется (через `dlsym()`) и динамически вызывается из функции в .so (она безусловно `-fPIC`) и вызвана из этого executable был тоже `pic` (а транслировать и собирать этот executable  можно как с `-fPIC`, так и с `-fPIE`)

Answer (score 1):

так и не получится слинковать при -fno-pic. линковщик (который неявно вызывает gcc) прямо об этом напишет при финальной сборке ELF.

Comment: Где поверяли? (у меня, например, сейчас (совсем не относится к проекту в вопросе)  `gcc fncall.c -rdynamic -ldl -lreadline -fno-pic` прекрасно отработал в `Linux wubu 4.4.0-42-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 23:11:45 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` с `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609`)

Comment: -f[no-]pic имеет смысл только при сборке библиотеки, которая потом будет динамически ресолвится при последующей линковке с fncall.c. На сборку основной программы -fpic рояля не играет, потому как отсутствует сам факт динамической линковки функций определенных непосредственно в fncall.c.

Comment: Имеет ли смысл `-fpic` или `-fno-pic` это другой вопрос. Вы пишете -- "`линковщик (который неявно вызывает gcc) прямо об этом напишет при финальной сборке ELF`". Я этого у себя не наблюдаю, вот и спросил (прямо и конкретно) -- "`Где проверяли?`"

Comment: где угодно. соберите либу с -fno-pic и попробуйте динамически прилинковать - это как два пальца об асфальт.

Comment: Вы вопрос-то читали? Речь о -fpic при компиляции **не либы**, а использующего ее бинарника.

Comment: там написано дословно "код" и слово "либы" не наблюдается. походу есть две серьезных проблемы 1) с формулированием вопроса 2) с признанием формулировки. баню как неадекватный